# How to iterate through array of arrays pandas and check first and last occurrence of an item

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, nested

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
    year    week    app_id  period
0   2015    22  [g8m4lecv, uyhsx6lo, u9ue1zzo, kw06m3f5, wvqhq...   2015-22
1   2015    23  [608a223c57e1174fc64775dd2fd8cda387cc4a47, ze4...   2015-23
2   2015    24  [kz8udlea, zwqo7j8w, 6d02c9d74b662369dc6c53ccc...   2015-24
3   2015    25  [fgs0qhtf, awkcmpns, e0iraf3a, oht91x5j, mv4uo...   2015-25
4   2015    26  [zwqo7j8w, dzdfiof5, phwoy1ea, e7hfx7mu, 40fdd...   2015-26
```

And a DataFrame of unique ids:

```
unique_app_ids
0   g8m4lecv
1   uyhsx6lo
2   u9ue1zzo
3   kw06m3f5
4   wvqhq7d7
5   fucjx9ar
6   ede963a7c7b854938c1196bb83dc3a0924951055
7   ze4rr0vi
```

What I want to do is, for each app_id in the unique_app_ids:

1. Find its first occurrence in terms of period in the array of arrays.
2. If it occurs, track the start date and increment weekly usage by one
3. Go to the next period, and if the app_id is still there, then increment by one
4. If the app id is not there, then stop incrementing.

I then want to have a column in the unique ids column of `weekly usage`.

Here is where I am at so far:

```
startperiod = True;
stopped = True;
usage = 0

weeklyadoption= adopters['app_id'].values;

def retention_rate(row):
    for app_id in retention['unique_app_ids']:
        for week in range(len(weeklyadoption)):
            if weeklyadoption[week].isin(app_id):
                stopped = False;
                usage+=1
            else:
                stopped = True;
                return usage

retention['weekly_retention']=retention.apply(retention_rate, axis=1)
```

Where `retention` is the dataframe of unique ids, and `adopters` is the array of arrays. However, I haven't tested the code because I am having trouble thinking about:

1. The code is currently going through each period and the moment even one period has nothing, it breaks out. However, lets say the first usage was 4 rows down, I only want to loop to start then, and then increment and break out from the period it starts.
2. How can I check not only that the app_id is in the current row, but is in all the other rows previous to this row since the start usage period.

**Edit**

Even the current code is not looping through. I get:

```
AttributeError: ("'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Note that `weeklyadoption` looks like this when printed out:

```
[([array],[array]....)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with what you are trying to do:

1. You have a `return` statement inside your loop, which is why it is exiting the loop.
2. It's unclear why you stored 2d data in an array and 1d in a DataFrame.  The opposite makes much more sense to me.

Here's my solution based on the implementation of those suggestions:

```
weekly_usage = {}
df['app_id_str'] = df['app_id'].apply(lambda x: ('|').join(x))
for app_id in unique_app_ids:
    temp = df[df['app_id_str'].str.contains(app_id)].sort('period')
    # at this point, if it's continuous, you can just take the length
    # start, end = temp['period'].min(), temp['period'].max() 
    duration = len(temp) #or you can use timedelta if you want a time difference
    weekly_usage[app_id] = duration
```

With that you'd have a dictionary of unique_ids and their durations and you can display them however you like.

Comment: Hi this almost gets me there, thank you! However len will always calculate the length of the array (always 14, number of time periods). Whereas what I want to do is to calculate the period from the first "True" to the first "False" e.g. `Name: app_id_str, dtype: bool
0      True
1      True
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False` was one of the key value pairs returned for one of the app_ids. Here, the number returned should be 2, as it was `True`, `True` then `False`. Not 14.